# Adding an apostrophe in subequations numbering/lettering

Tags: equations, numbering, subequations

I use subequations with code like this

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
1=2\\
3=4\\
z=x\\
x=y
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

and it tags the equations as

> (1a), (1b), (1c) and (1d).

I want to change it so that it instead
tags it like

> (1a), (1b), (1b') and (1c),

i.e., I want to add an apostrophe for some of the tags (of my choosing) which should freeze the letter to the previous one, and then to resume as normal. How could I do that automatically (I don't want to manually tag the equation myself)?

Comment: `\tag{\theequation'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\tag` with a generated number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
1&=2\\
3&=4\\
z&=x\tag{\theequation'}\\
x&=y
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```